# How can you set the display size of a TileMap (CCTMXTiledMap) layer in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am wanting to split the screen down the middle of my app, with one half showing a map, and the other half showing a character's inventory / list of commands. Is there a way to have the map only render on the left hand side of the screen? e.g. something like the following code:

```
    // Load in the tile map file
    self.tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"TileMap.tmx"];

    // Set the backogrund to be the background layer in that map
    self.background = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Background"];
    self.foreground = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Foreground"];

    // Add the map to this window, with a low z-index
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // This doesn't work, as there is no set on boundingBox
    // And I not sure it would anyway
    _tileMap.boundingBox = (CGRect){0,0,winSize.width/2,winSize.height};

    [self addChild:_tileMap z:-1];
```

I am currently getting around in by putting a layer on top of the map covering up that side of the screen with a box, but it feels very hacky / like it's going to backfire on me. One benefit of this approach is that I could potentially just "fade" the inventory screen away and the user will have access to the full map until they bring it back again (but it would cause problems with them reaching the right hand side of map etc)

Comment: cocos2d always renders the entire map, so overlay is probably the only solution

Comment: Overlay makes sense. Why do you think it's hacky?